# GridSortOptions object not being passed to controller method

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller method signature of...

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, GridSortOptions sortOptions, bool? listViewSelected)
{
    // do something
}
```

and I have a ajax function to call that method

```
function loadVehicles() {
    if (page > -1 && !_inCallback) {
        _inCallback = true;
        page++;
        var url = "/memberdashboard.aspx/SearchResults/Index";

        var params = {
            page: page,
            sortOptions: { "Column": "@Model.GridSortOptions.Column", "Direction": "@Model.GridSortOptions.Direction" },
            listViewSelected: '@Model.IsListViewSelected',
        };

        $("div#loading").html('<img src="../../Content/images/InfiniteScrolling/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            data: params,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    $("#content").append(data);
                } else {
                    page = -1;
                }
                _inCallback = false;
                $('div#loading').empty();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Unable to fetch any additional information.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Investigation of the html code validated that 'var params' has the proper values however, when I step into the controller method, 'page' has the proper value,  'listViewSelected' has the proper value but 'sortOptions' does not. Any thoughts?

Comment: How does the url look like in your AJAX request (you can use fiddler or your browser developer tools to inspect the request)? What is this `GridSortOptions` type? How does it look like and where is it definied?

Comment: request url =  http://localhost:30593/memberdashboard.aspx/SearchResults/Index?page=4&sortOptions%5BColumn%5D=make&sortOptions%5BDirection%5D=Ascending&listViewSelected=False

Object Type =  MvcContrib.UI.Grid.GridSortOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using GET with complex objects (e.g. not just simple key/value parts) the   `$.ajax` does not serialize your data how ASP.NET MVC likes it

JQuery creates: `sortOptions[Column]=make&sortOptions[Direction]=Ascending` while ASP.NET MVC needs `Column=make&Direction=Ascending`

So you have two options:

- Use POST instead of GET when you are dealing with multiple complex parameters
- Change your `params` to use the correct (for ASP.NET MVC) property names (so your params object should be "flat" so no nested objects when working using GET) :

  ```
  var params = {
     page: page,
     listViewSelected: '@Model.IsListViewSelected',
     Column: "@Model.GridSortOptions.Column", 
     Direction: "@Model.GridSortOptions.Direction"
  };
  ```

  if you are dealing with more complex objects in your action like:

  ```
  public class GridParams {
        public int? page { get; set; } 
        public GridSortOptions sortOptions { get; set; } 
        public bool? listViewSelected { get; set; }
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index(GridParams gridParams)
  {
  }
  ```

  Then you need to use `"."` in the property names:

  ```
  var params = {
     page: page,
     listViewSelected: '@Model.IsListViewSelected'
  }

  params["sortOptions.Column"] = "@Model.GridSortOptions.Column";
  params["sortOptions.Direction"] = "@Model.GridSortOptions.Direction";
  ```

Comment: Thanks nemevs. I found that out today as well. I also found that MVC is smart enough to understand where the params are supposed to be. So assigning my params variable like so, also works.                 var params = {
                    page: page,
                    Column: "@Model.GridSortOptions.Column",
                    Direction: "@Model.GridSortOptions.Direction",
                    listViewSelected: '@Model.IsListViewSelected',
                };